# Splitting at every n-th separator, and keeping the character

Tags: java, string, list, split

I need a function to change a String like this:

```
Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Pink, Gray, Purple
```

Into a String[] like this:

```
Red, Green,
Blue, Orange,
Pink, Gray,
Purple
```

In this example the character is `,`  and splitting it every 2nd.
There are many similar functions online to this one, but they all remove the character.

Comment: You can use String's [`indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) repeatedly to find the index of the n-th delimeter.

Comment: And how exactly could that be done? I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Walking through the input string from left to right using an integer to keep track of your current position.  Use the indexOf function to advance to the next comma character.  Then every other comma add a newline.  There's a special case when you reach the end of the input string and there's an odd number of words.

Answer (score 1):

this should work fine.

```
    String sample = "Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Pink, Gray, Purple";
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern firstPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z-\\s]*,[a-zA-Z-\\s]*,|[a-zA-Z-\\s]*,[a-zA-Z-\\s]*");
    Matcher firstMatcher = firstPattern.matcher(sample);
    Pattern secondPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z-\\s]*$");
    Matcher secondMatcher = secondPattern.matcher(sample);

    while (firstMatcher.find()) {
        output.add(firstMatcher.group());
    }
    if ((output.size() * 2) < sample.split(",").length)
        if (secondMatcher.find())
            output.add(secondMatcher.group(0));
```

output:

```
Red, Green,
 Blue, Orange,
 Pink, Gray,
 Purple
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple solution that works in linear time O(n)

[image]

where groupSize = 2

```
    public static ArrayList<String> splitPairs(String input, int groupSize) {
    String[] inputArray = input.split(",");
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0;

    while (index < inputArray.length) {
        StringBuilder newItem = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < groupSize && index < inputArray.length; i++, index++) {
            if (i != 0)
                newItem.append(", ");

            newItem.append(inputArray[index].trim());

            if (i == groupSize - 1) {
                newItem.append(",");
            }
        }

        if (newItem.length() > 0) {
            result.add(newItem.toString());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you have an even number the last one (for example if we remove purple) will keep the comma.

Answer (score 0):

A not very good solution may help you.

**First**:split the string by ',' into String[]

**Second**:split String array into array of string array and every small array have 0,1 or 2 elements

**Third**:join the small string array.

A solution use google guava:

```java
String input = "Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Pink, Gray, Purple";
List<List<String>> lists = Lists.partition(Arrays.asList(input.split(",")),2);
String[] outputs = new String[lists.size()];
lists.stream().map(strings -> String.join(", ", strings)).map(String::trim)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(outputs);
for (String output: outputs) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach withouth regex, using the `indexOf` method that i mentioned in the comment. It's a little oldschool and does all the things manually, essentially just using `indexOf` and `substring`, which makes it fulfill your "keeping the character" requirement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input = "Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Pink, Gray, Purple";
  final int n = 2;
  final char delim = ',';
  nthSep(input, n, delim).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static LinkedList<String> nthSep(String input, int n, char delim) {
  LinkedList<String> res = new LinkedList<>();
  int startsplit = 0;
  int delimcount = 0;
  int curInd = 0;
  //repeat until no separator is found
  while (true) {
    //remember the index of the current split part
    startsplit = curInd;
    delimcount = 0;
    //find the separator n times
    while (delimcount < n) {
      curInd = input.indexOf(delim, curInd+1);
      if (curInd == -1) {
        break;
      }
      delimcount++;
    }

    if(curInd != -1){
      //add a result to the list, then move on with the next split part
      res.add(input.substring(startsplit, curInd+1));
      curInd++;
    } else {
      //so further separator is found, add the whole remaining input
      res.add(input.substring(startsplit));
      break;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```